# Modify IPN Listener to handle multiple custom variables passed through from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Since paypal does not allow multiple IPN Notifications, I am using an IPN broadcast script to send the transaction information to two IPN Listener Scripts.  My main IPN listener uses the data to mark the transaction as PAID in the database; the secondary IPN listener uses the data to assign commission to the referring agent.  The problem is that each of the IPN listener scripts require separate date in the Custom Variable Field.

Custom Field required for Listener 1:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $transaction_id .  '>
```

Custom Field required for Listener 2:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. '>
```

In order to send these two variables through paypal, I have modified the custom variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $transaction_id .  '|' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. '
```

When the IPN information is received back from PayPal, I am using the IPN Broadcast script from [CodeSeekah](http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/11/how-to-setup-multiple-ipn-receivers-in-paypal/) to pass the response to the two separate IPN Listeners.

When the IPN listeners receive the information from paypal, it must validate the information with PayPal, so both variables need to be included with the IPN Listener script.  But my question is, how do I customize the IPN Listener to "Pull" the appropriate data from the IPN transaction and disregard the information that was passed through for the other script?

Comment: Thsi is just a result of your poor architecture. You don't need to validate the IPN twice for example. You should have only one actual IPN listener, and have it call as many other things as you like, none of which should themselves be IPN listeners. (Edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to concur with @EJP's comment and suggest that you eliminate the additional IPN listener.  There's no need for that based on what you've explained here.  You can do all the updates you need within a single listener.

As for your specific question, you can pull the individual values back out of the CUSTOM parameter like this.

```
$custom_split = explode('|',$_POST['custom']);
$transaction_id = $custom_split[0];
$ip_address = $custom_split[1];
```

Comment: it really helped me, good suggestion. I think we don't need IPN broadcaster. Instead, we can just pass different data via **$_POST['custom']** variable in PHP post data.

Comment: I personally like delimiting multiple values with chr(1) instead of "|".  Sometimes "|" is a legitimate character in a custom value, but there's a much lower chance that chr(1) will be a legitimate character.